# Why TypeScript compiler doesnt allow to return instance of class

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

Here is a example to illustrate a problem:

First I have a Typescript Definition for React where we have a definition for the Component:

```
class Component<P, S> implements ComponentLifecycle<P, S> {
    static propTypes: ValidationMap<any>;
    static contextTypes: ValidationMap<any>;
    static childContextTypes: ValidationMap<any>;
    static defaultProps: Props<any>;

    constructor(props?: P, context?: any);
    setState(f: (prevState: S, props: P) => S, callback?: () => any): void;
    setState(state: S, callback?: () => any): void;
    forceUpdate(callBack?: () => any): void;
    render(): JSX.Element;
    props: P;
    state: S;
    context: {};
    refs: {
        [key: string]: Component<any, any>
    };
}
```

Then in Application I created class that extends Component.

```
class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
}
```

And I would like to have a function which returns a instance of Component.

```
function Test<T extends React.Component<any, any>>(): T
{
    return App;
}
```

Typescript compiler doesn't allow me to do that. The error is:

> Property 'setState' is missing in type 'typeof App'

I don't understand it because class should inherit everything from Component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you should write

```
function Test<T extends React.Component<any, any>>(): T
{
    return new App();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right! It was very long day for me.

I still dont understand something. I have tsd for react-redux with following definitions:

```
export interface ClassDecorator {
    <T extends ComponentLifecycle<any, any>>(target:T): T;
}

export function connect(mapStateToProps?: MapStateToProps,
                          mapDispatchToProps?: MapDispatchToPropsFunction|MapDispatchToPropsObject,
                          mergeProps?: MergeProps,
                          options?: Options):  ClassDecorator;
```

And in other file where I use it I have

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

And it's working. Why I don't need to pass new App()??
The App is the same class as in first question.
The ComponentLifecycle is an interface implemented by React.Component. When I change ComponentLifecycle to Component in tsd file my code doesn't compile.

Comment: React components are always passed around as *constructor functions*, not class instances. You should basically never be writing `new App()` in user code -- React is the library in charge of managing class instantiation.

Comment: I know that I shouldnt create instances of React Components. Problem is that I don't know why I can pass constructor function of React Component as an argument of method in this concrete example and why I can't do it when I change definition from ComponentLifecycle<any,any> to Component<any,any>. Component is a class and ComponentLifecycle is an interface, but it shouldnt matter here

Comment: Ok. I found problem. The ComponentLifecycle interface has only optional types inside definition. That casues that compiler allows you to pass constructor function.

Comment: Posting another answer is not a place for discussions…